# How to find earliest and latest date from event list, angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need earliest and latest date from event list. I attached the screenshot of console log message.

```
  events: Event[] = [];
  count=0;
  minDate = new Date();
  maxDate = new Date();
  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise <void> {
    this.events = await this.eventService.getEvents();
    this.eventCounter();
  }
    eventCounter(): void {
     for (let event of this.events) {
          this.count= this.count +1; 
          console.log(event.date_of_event);
        }
   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR8mV.png)

Comment: Simplest solution is to sort them using the array `sort` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()`:

```
const min = this.events.reduce((a,v) => Date.parse(p) < Date.parse(v) ? p : v)
const max = this.events.reduce((a,v) => Date.parse(p) > Date.parse(v) ? p : v)
```

We use the `Date.parse()` value when comparing because it represents a timestamp value, which is a number.